# How to setup port-forwarding for multiple websites?

Tags: ssh

I need to port forward 2 websites simultaneously on a macOS.

E.g.:

```
sudo ssh -L abc.com:443:abc.com:443 user@proxy.host
sudo ssh -L xyz.com:443:xyz.com:443 user@proxy.host
```

Right now xyz won't work because port is already bound.

I can't use SOCKS proxy because I need to run some software that requires direct connection.